# New subnet already exists in MAAS

Tags: networking, maas

So, I am creating a new subnet in my MAAS environment. 192.168.0.0/24. When I try to make it, MAAS gives me "Error: Subnet with this Cidr already exists."
Even though the subnet does not exist in the list of subnets. Anyone know where I can make sure Maas does not think it already should exist?

Comment: Which subnets are listed in the subnet list?

Comment: @vidarlo, it has been fixed now. Though I do not quite know how. The subnets listed did not include the one I wanted to create.